# How to get 1 element from a table based on data-stat

Tags: java, jsoup

Page URL: https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/collijo01.html

Table location: `<tr id="per_game.2019 class="full_table">`

Element I want: `<td class="right" data-stat="fg3a_per_g">2.5</td>`

With the 2.5 being what I want. I used to grab the entire table then cycle to this information, but I have found this to be more work than trying to grab based on the data-stat name. However so far I have failed

Question is: Can jsoup grab info based on data-stat section?

Code:

```
public static void getDataTest(String url) throws IOException
{
    String html = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().body();
    html = html.replaceAll("<!--", "");
    html = html.replaceAll("-->", "");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element tableElements = doc.getElementById("table#fg3a_per_g");

    System.out.print("Element found was: " + tableElements);
}
```

Note I've also tried "fg3a_per_g" by itself without table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can jsoup grab info based on data-stat section?

Sure:

```
Element element = doc.select("td[data-stat=fg3a_per_g]").first();
```

What you call `section` is actually called `attribute`. Also take a look at more CSS selectors. You can't use all of them with Jsoup, but the basic ones are supported and very useful: 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks CSS isn't my forte